# To find the moment of inertia about co-ordinate axes of a tetrahedron in the first octant bounded by x+y+z=1

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus

I need to find the moment of inertia about co-ordinate axes of a tetrahedron in the first octant bounded by $x+y+z=1$.

My attempt:

$x+y+z = 1$ forms the base of the tetrahedron and my limits for integration based on integrating first with respect to z are:

limits for $z: [0,1-x-y]$

limits for $y:[0,1-x]$

limits for $x:[0,1]$

The formula for moment of inertia in 3 dimensions is:

$ I_x = \iiint( y^2+ z^2 ) \delta dV $ where $\delta$ is the density function

$ I_y = \iiint( x^2+ z^2 ) \delta dV $

$ I_z = \iiint( x^2+ y^2 ) \delta dV $

then I found the moment of inertia about x axis,

$I_x = \int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}\int_0^{1-x-y}( y^2+ z^2 )  dzdydz$

$I_x = \int_0^1\int_0^{1-x}( y^2z+ \frac{z^3}{3} )|_0^{1-x-y}  dydz$

.

.

.
$I_x = \frac{1}{30}$
Similarly for y and z.
For now, I just want to confirm whether I'm moving in the right direction and whether I've missed something or not. Thank you.

Edit: As far as I know, tetrahedron has to do with triple integration. However, the official method for this question is double integration for x and y moments and triple for z. **Why is this so?**

Comment: I see it right. But I did not know about that official method (taken apart the very same definition of momentum of inertia). Can you give a link?

Comment: finally someone answered! That was just a hint from my professor but my question is this, I would find Ix and Iy using triple integration just like I did for Iz. But I'm not sure why? Why can't it be done by double integration alone? Thank you

Comment: As far as the definition is concerned, the moment of inertia is the weighted sum of the function $\rho(\vec r)$, the density, over the entire space with weight $\mathbb a^2$, with $\mathbb a$ the distance to some line, so is, is the integral over the space of $\rho(\vec r)\mathbb a^2$. I'd say the triple integral is the natural way for the calculation of the moment of inertia. Sometimes the symmetry of $\rho$ makes possible to do with a double o single integral (e.g. a cone), but to my understanding even in this case it needs some previous use of integrals.